# TSQL Code formatter - SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a free code formatter available for TSQL - SQL Server 2005/2008. I found few most of which asks to copy paste code online in an applet. I am looking for a desktop version. Tried toad for sql server but formatting is not supported in freeware.
If anyone has any work-around please share it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) (free addon for SSMS).

One of the features is formatting (http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=3), though I don't know what level you want your SQL formatted - maybe you could clarify?

Comment: looks great, thanks. How do I get it to indent the code. SELECT, UPDATE statements correctly formatted, Code inside begin and end to be a tab in etc

Comment: @anivas - it doesn't do those things

Answer (score 7):

I've been working on a formatter for the past few months, I just release the official version v1.0, with no (major) known issues.

It's available for immediate online use at http://poorsql.com, and the project with SSMS Add-In, command-line formatter ready-to-download is available at http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx.

I know it's been a long while since this question was posted, but I'd love any sort of feedback.

(Edit: updated status)

Comment: Tao - Thanks for this tool. I use the SMSS add-in and it works great. I like the formatting. Keep up the good work, maybe add some options on handling of lines, so for e.g. allow elements to be on same line instead of newline.

Answer (score 0):

SQLISE has a formating function, you can set a number of formatting options. It is free. It is a codeplex project based on PowerShell.

Drawback it removes all comments
[link text](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This online tool does excellent sql formatting.
http://sqlserverlearner.com/online-tools/tsql-code-formatter

I use it to format tsql code

Comment: Topic opener is looking specifically for a desktop tool.